# Error in switch in android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Hello Guys I am using a switch created from code instead of xml.
But only in android 5.0 i am getting this error in other version its working fine.

```
12-08 08:48:30.417: E/InputEventReceiver(31006): Exception dispatching input event.
12-08 08:48:30.417: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.getPadding(android.graphics.Rect)' on a null object reference
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.widget.Switch.hitThumb(Switch.java:694)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.widget.Switch.onTouchEvent(Switch.java:711)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5223)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-08 08:48:46.449: E/MessageQueue-JNI(31006):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-08 08:48:55.673: E/ACRA(31006): ACRA caught a NullPointerException exception for com.sa.appinboxtest. Building report.
```

Comment: Set a non-null thumb drawable.

Comment: Also, this has been fixed in our internal branch. It will always be broken in API 21, though, so you'll still need a non-null thumb drawable. Consider using anything other than Switch if you don't need a thumb.

Comment: How to set a non-null thumb?
sorry i am a newbie in android so can you help me for this.

Answer (score 1):

It is Android reported bug. If you want fix this issue add below properties to switch

```
android:thumb="@drawable/my_thumb_icon"
android:track="@drawable/my_track_icon"
```

this will work for below 5.0 also

for reference [Click here](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1704)

Comment: ok but i have created some other demos and in that switch is working fine but only in that project it is not showing proper.
can it be the issue of theme.
and yes i have created switch from code not from xml.

Comment: No it not theme issue, It is Android 5.0 bug. It is reported bug and they accepted. for reference go through this link https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1704

Comment: what is that my_thumb_icon and my_track_icon?

Comment: moreover link broken!